# Best practices around writing testable extension methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, programming-practices, testing

I’m currently working in C# and I’d like to write and extension method against a type. There is a small amount of repeated logic between classes surrounding JSON deserialization, using the `JsonSerializer` class from .NET, that I expect would need to be changed for each one if it were to be updated. The problem I’m running into is that the extension method isn’t mockable when writing unit tests due to `JsonSerializer` being a static class. If I were to use a regular class to abstract this logic I could write and interface to encapsulate the `JsonSerializer` class which would allow me to inject a locked version for testing. However since the extension method must reside in a static class this approach won’t work.

Are there any best practices for writing testable extension methods which contain references to static classes or is this not possible?

Comment: Why do you need to mock JsonSerializer? I thought those static methods were idempotent.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more. What I'm getting is, you're writing an extension method against a type (or is it several types?) that has some logic that is repeated in a couple of different scenarios, and you want to pull that out in a *shared* component covered by a test (basically, you want to apply DRY)? If that's the case, I'm not sure that mocking `JsonSerializer` would necessarily help you test that logic, unless you want to use it as a spy to check if certain methods get called. It would help if you provided more info on where/how the code repetition occurs?

Comment: What you could do is, instead of having your extension methods execute the serialization logic, have them return *an instance of a serializer object* (basically, the extension method provides a uniform interface to the developers using the type, and picks the serializer class for them: `someThing.Serialize()` turns to `someThing.GetSerializer().Serialize()`). You then write the test the against your serializer class (or interface).

Comment: Your question is unclear. On one hand, you wrote *"that the extension method isn’t mockable"* - so you want to mock this method and test some code which uses this method? On the aother hand,  you wrote *"testable extension methods"* - which indicates you ask about how to test the extension method itself. Could you please clarify what you are talking about? Maybe a code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem I’m running into is that the extension method isn’t mockable

Extension methods are static, and statics aren't mockable, nor should they be.

The syntax for calling an extension method may *look like* a class method (e.g. `myObj.Foo()`), but it's pure syntactic sugar to hide the real static call that's happening (e.g. `MyHelper.Foo(myObj)`).

When statics methods are pure, i.e. only input/output driven without any state or side effects (as statics should be), you can simply use the real method in your other tests, **provided** you also test that method itself.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of people telling you there’s no reason to stub these methods. And there are cases where they are right. But sometimes you have a good reason to stub them.

A bad reason would be simply because you want to stub everything that isn’t your class. Your class will depend on things outside it no matter what you do. So don’t blindly stub everything.

A good reason would be you need to test stuff that takes too long to serialize and are happy with a cached result. In such a case simple indirection allows mocking. Just because a function uses a static function doesn’t mean it must be static.

If you think that won’t work because you want to test the call to the static function then you’re testing the wrong thing. Put behaviors under test. Not structure. Let the compiler worry about that.